# Total number of Strings for given weight and length?

Tags: combinatorics

I am given length of a lowercase string and weight of string.
Weight of string can be defined as summation of weight value of all its character.
Weight value of a character is defined as: 
 *a* has weight *1*

*b* has weight *2*

.
.
.
 *z* has weight *26*.

So weight of string *abcd* (say) is 1+2+3+4 = 10.

Hence, if I am given weight of string *x* and length of string *n*, then How many such string are possible ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: The topic here is [integer compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) (ordered summands with specified number of summands/string length and total/string weight, with the subtle requirement of no summand more than $26$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the $n$ string elements represented by $p_i$ have weights $x_i$, $i=1,2, \ldots,n$.

Now we have $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i=x$$ and we have to find the total number of positive integral solutions.

Using [Stars and Bars method](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj-msC-vKLYAhVJMI8KHekzAJEQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FStars_and_bars_(combinatorics)&usg=AOvVaw37v2KDIu7xbHkm7lAS3T6N), you can easily show that the total number of positive integral solutions, possible in this case is $\binom{x-1}{n-1}$.

Comment: But this won't work when the weights are restricted. In the question $1\le x_i \le26$. For example, given $n=4, x=30$ then "aabz" is valid but "aaa[27]" fails.

Comment: @nickgard Yes, it works still. The answer would be different, however. Wait, I am adding that link. https://trungpham90.wordpress.com/2015/12/28/beautiful-problem-number-of-integer-solution-for-equation-with-constraints/